# How to get the latest day from a list of dates in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, date, datetime

Im looking a clean way to get an array of dates and considering that the whole range in one year.

```
days  = [1, 31]
dates = []
(start_date..end_date).each do |date|
  dates << if days.include? date.day
end
```

What I´m looking is an array with all dates from `days` and if the day won't exist in the month use the latest one.

```
[nov 1, nov 30, dec 1, dec 31 ...]
```

Comment: What format are the dates in? Your example seems arbitrary and isn't Ruby code. It's also not clear what your requirements are here. Why not use `reject` on your values instead of this rather arbitrary `<<`?

Comment: You can use `beginning_of_month` and `end_of_month` from `ActiveSupport`

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'date'

days       = [1, 15, 31]
  #=> [1, 15, 31]
last_day   = days.max
  #=> 31
start_date = Date.parse 'Jan 4, 2016'
  #=> #<Date: 2016-01-04 ((2457392j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
end_date   = Date.parse 'Nov 16, 2016'
  #=> #<Date: 2016-11-16 ((2457709j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> 

(start_date..end_date).select do |d|
  days.include?(d.day) || (((d+1).month != d.month) && (d.day < last_day))
end.map {|d| d.strftime("%b %-d")}
  #=> ["Jan 15", "Jan 31", "Feb 1",  "Feb 15", "Feb 29", "Mar 1",  "Mar 15",
  #    "Mar 31", "Apr 1",  "Apr 15", "Apr 30", "May 1",  "May 15", "May 31",
  #    "Jun 1",  "Jun 15", "Jun 30", "Jul 1",  "Jul 15", "Jul 31", "Aug 1",
  #    "Aug 15", "Aug 31", "Sep 1",  "Sep 15", "Sep 30", "Oct 1",  "Oct 15",
  #    "Oct 31", "Nov 1",  "Nov 15"]
```

Each date object `d` between `start_date` and `end_date` is selected if the logical expression returns `true`. The logical expression reads, "a) the given array `days` includes `d.day` *or* b) `d.day` is the last day of the month *and* that day is less than `last_day`". `d.day` is the last day of the month if the month in which `d` falls is different than the month in which the following day (`d+1`) falls. (If `d` falls on December 31 (month `12`), the following day falls in month `1`, so we must test `12 != 1` rather than `12 < 1`.)

See [Date#strftime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime) for an explanation of the formatting codes.

`start_date` and `end_date` can fall in different years.